# Uninstall parental control plugin in system settings

Tags: wingpanel, pantheon-terminal

Im using Elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya.
After a recent update, i got these new settings in my system settings.
A parental control, new network, new universal access, new mouse & touchpad plugins were added. The wingpanel takes some time to load the clock and other icons after startup. My software-center wont start either.

This is the message I get after I try to start software center from terminal:

```
** (software-center:7872): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-WYbumqnp5N: Connection refused
2015-10-22 17:44:05,005 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 407, in __init__
self.icons)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 79, in __init__
self._get_emblems(self.icons)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/historypane.py", line 199, in _get_emblems
pb = icons.load_icon(emblem, self.ICON_SIZE, 0)
gi._glib.GError: Error opening file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I read somewhere that deleting the parental control plugin from system settings would rectify the problem of wingpanel loading delay.

Comment: Nope. Its not present there.
http://postimg.org/image/p9149v5cp/

Thats how my system settings look like now.

Comment: Did you check that link in my previous comment? There the parental control plugin is visible along with other settings like network which have multiple plugins and they are all diff from each other.

Comment: No. I just did the usual system updates and all these new stuff popped up in my system settings. I think they updated the kernel and added new switchboard items

Comment: Parental Control Section:
http://postimg.org/image/xl7y1nmeb/

Comment: thanks =) btw you have two universal access in settings :).

Comment: Not just universal access, network, mouse & pointer too

new network plugin:
http://postimg.org/image/flrtsqdox/

Comment: The initial Network plugin:
http://postimg.org/image/9cg9n5zrp/

Comment: please run `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall` and see if parental control visible

Comment: please run the commands `cd /usr/share/applications` and see `parental control` is available

Comment: When i ran the command:
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall

I saw =>  switchboard-plug-parental-controls  install

Comment: what about ^ command `cd /usr/share/applications`?and `/usr/bin`

Comment: I couldnt find it when i ran the other command though.... :/

Its there in /usr/bin as well:
parental-control-cli   and  parental-control-daemon

Comment: And I'm really thankful for sparing your precious time! ^^

Comment: I too curious to find solution ;)try to come [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25374/elementary-os)

Comment: I dont have that much rep points to chat   :P

Comment: problem solved?